# String Variable Argument Lists in C++

Tags: c++, string, list, arguments, variadic-functions

I'm trying to use a variable argument list to make NPCs in my text-based RPG talk easily. There's so many errors I'm not even bothering to post them - I gather I'm using this so wrong you won't need the output.
If you do, of course I'll post it.

Here's the two files you'll need:

```
//Globals.h

#ifndef _GLOBALS_
#define _GLOBALS_

//global variables

#include "Library.h"
//prototypes
bool Poglathon();
void NPCTalk(string speaker,string text,...);

//functions
void NPCTalk(string speaker,string text,...){
    va_list list;
    va_start(list,text);
    while(true){
        string t = va_arg(list,string);
        if (t.compare("")==0)
            break;
        cout << speaker << ": "<< t << endl << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}

#endif
```

And the other one:

```
//Library.h

#ifndef _LIBRARY_H_
#define _LIBRARY_H_

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "Globals.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>

#endif
```

Comment: If you want to use `std::string` you'll have to include `<string>`.

Comment: It's not a good idea to try to pass non-POD types (such as `std::string`) to variadic functions. The results will be non-portable, and problems it causes may be hard to debug.

Comment: You're trying to code C using the language C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about a vector of strings?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

void NPCTalk(std::string const& speaker, std::vector<std::string> const& text)
{
    for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = text.begin();
                                                  it != text.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << speaker << ": " << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's this `const&` for? I'll try that.

Comment: You'll get a non-modifiable reference of the object.

Comment: @Pig Head: You don't copy the whole vector, which may be slow because it might be pretty big if the NPC likes to talk. A reference behaves similar to a pointer and doesn't make a copy.

Comment: Okay - I'm getting the error "Namespace 'std' has no member 'vector'". Odd?

Comment: @Pig: Did you `#include <vector>`?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include vector. Thanks.